# Send email from UNIX command with attachment and HTML message body

Tags: shell, email, unix, sendmail, mailx

This may sound like a dumb question, but I have tried and searched a lot of options, and none met my requirements

I am trying to send a mail with a report from unix command line using a bash script, I managed to send it with body and attachment using the mailx service, but the body is unformatted and not pleasing to the eye

```
(echo "$(cat /tmp/report_summary.html)";uuencode /tmp/report_details.xls report_details.xls) |/usr/bin/mailx -s "Report for XYZ" $MAIL_GRP
```

I tried the sendmail option, which formats the message body perfectly, but does not have an option for attachment

```
(
echo "From: From@xyz.vom";
echo "To: Address@xyz.vom";
echo "Subject: Test Message 1 2 3";
echo "Content-Type: text/html";
echo "MIME-Version: 1.0";
echo "Content-Disposition: inline";
echo "<HTML><BODY><PRE>";
cat /tmp/report_details.html;
echo "</PRE></BODY></HTML>";
) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
```

I do not have mutt option, but I tried sendmail, mailx and mail service and none is able to help me meet my apparently simple need

Unix OS: Solaris 10 8/07 s10s_u4wos_12b SPARC

Note: Don't tag this as duplicate with existing answers, as they either have option to send attachment or html body or attachment with plain body.

Comment: IIRC, there needs to be a blank line between headers and content, and the line endings should be CRLF (although that probably doesn't matter).

Comment: FWIW, your `sendmail` command worked fine when I tried it on my Ubuntu 16.04 system using the Postfix implementation of the `sendmail` binary.

Comment: @Anthony Geoghegan: Both work fine individually, but as I said send mail only sends body, does not have option for attachment

Answer (score 1):

Sending "single MIME part" using sendmail (low level command) is pretty easy.

Your script grave bugs:

1. Missing "END OF HEADERS" (empty line)
2. Missing `-i` sendmail command line option

Your script suggested improvements:

1. Moving recipients from headers to sendmail command line
2. Missing `charset` in Content-type (unless you use US-ASCII)
3. Missing Content-Transfer-Encoding (unless you use US-ASCII = 7bit)

Corrected script:

```
#!/bin/sh
(
# Email headers and html header body in body 
cat - <<END
From: From@xyz.vom
To: Address@xyz.vom
Subject: Test Message 1 2 3
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Disposition: inline

<HTML><BODY><PRE>
END
# file to be "HTMLized" 
cat /tmp/report_details.html
# html footer in body
cat - << END_FOOTER
</PRE></BODY></HTML>
END_FOOTER
)
| /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -- 'Address@xyz.vom'
```

Comment: My sendmail script works fine, I am not able to send attachment, as mentioned in my question

Comment: `sendmail` command (provided by sendmail/postfix/exim/...) is a "low level tool".  There is no command line option for attachment(s) - you must generate properly formatted message yourself.  It is pretty simple for "single MIME part" message.